# How would I pass a iCheck Checkbox value to Laravel?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, icheck

I'm trying to implement a purchased theme, and it uses iCheck to theme it's checkbox's. It however does not change or add a value on/off or the checked option to the input, it only does it in the div that it wraps the input in. How would I go about getting the value to my backend Laravel Application? I currently have the following code.

```
<label><input type="checkbox" name="terms">&nbsp;
I agree with the Terms and Conditions</label>
```

And

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').iCheck({
    checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-grey',
    increaseArea: '20%' // optional
});
```

Comment: It sends the value to the server check this demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nj6aoeso/

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution, up for other answers if someone else has something better.

I just created a hidden input and set the value to 0. Then did a bind to the ifClicked event and toggled the value in the hidden input.

```
$('#rememberme').on('ifClicked', function(event){
    var value = $('#remembermehidden').val();
    if(value == "0") 
    {
        $('#remembermehidden').val('1');
    } else {
        $('#remembermehidden').val('0');
    } 
});
```